# SagePay RedirectURL failure

Tags: asp.net, server, opayo

Using server integration and .net, I post the original request to SagePay and get the NextURL fine, and so go to the payment pages... step through them OK, but then I get the error:

> Server error 5006: Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.
>
> HTTP error 500: The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.

But I **am** sending a RedirectionURL (though the docs call is RedirectURL, which is somewhat confusing - anyway, I've tried using both.  This si what I'm sending back from my NotificatioURL - what's wrong?

```
      Dim sb As New StringBuilder
  sb.Append("Status=OK")  
  sb.Append("&StatusDetail=Fine")
  sb.Append("&RedirectURL=https://mydomain.co.uk/sagepay.aspx")

  Dim urlTEST As String = "https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp"
  Dim urlLIVE As String = "https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp"

  Try
     Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString)

     Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(urlTEST)

     request.Method = "POST"
     request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     request.ContentLength = data.Length
     ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf ValidateRemoteSSLCertificate
     ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

     Dim stream = request.GetRequestStream()
     stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
     stream.Close()

    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
     response.Close()

  Catch ex As Exception
    'log error

  End Try
```

Update:  I gather this POST (unlike the initial one with the basket info) requires that the data be sent plain text key-value pairs separated by CrLf's, so I amended this to

```
          Dim sb As New StringBuilder
  sb.AppendLine("Status=OK")  
  sb.AppendLine("StatusDetail=Fine")
  sb.Append("RedirectURL=https://mydomain.co.uk/sagepay.aspx")
```

but it still fails with the same errors.  I also tried using, instead of the WebRequst class, the simpler:

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reply As String = client.UploadString(urlTEST, sb.ToString)
```

But still no joy. Also tried changing the request.ContentType to "text/plain", but nope.

Come on, someone, please - this si basic to the their operations, someone must have done it....

Comment: I think I've seen this (it was a hilw ago). The fix was to avoid a redirection on the callback URL (old config lead to passing http when it should have been https, but not user visible because of automatic redirection).

Comment: umm.. sorry, can you elaborate?  Not sure I follow what you're saying....

Comment: I'll try again: our callback URL returns a redirect (from http to https) and SagePay didn't like it.

Comment: OK... but mine isn't redirected - the URL is https and it goes straight there. (or should do...)

Answer (score 1):

Blimey - it never pays to be clever. This script doesn't require WebRequest or anything, just write to the simple Response object. Sigh.. as [Linus said](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7e/e6/1b/7ee61b213ab62a3c6179b78020b35da6--linus-peanuts-peanuts-comics.jpg) ....

Comment: Hi. It's a long shot, but I've got the same problem you had. What did you do when you said "just write to the simple Response object"?

Comment: IDK what I meant either!  But this is what I do now, and it works:
On the web checkout page I collect the various details about the sale, and create the so-called PaymentRegistrationMessage - this gets POSTed off to SagePay using a simple WebRequest object and response stream read to obtain the NextURL, after which a simple Response.Redirect(NextURL) does the trick...

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the same thing about the same time you sent this reply. In case it's of use to anyone else, for the final transaction confirmation step, you need to clear the response headers, buffer, set content type to text/plain, then set up a string with the status and redirectURL (separated by \r\n) the simply do a Response.Write to the string, then Response.End() seems to be necessary, too - and return; - don't know why.