# SagePay Server Integration

Tags: opayo

I'm integrating SagePay Server and am stuck at step 4 here: https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo-server/taking-payments

I get this error: Server error 5006: Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.

I know there are quite a lot of suggestions for this error out there. That it basically means there is something wrong with your code on the Notification URL.

I know it is completing the previous steps fine (I get the correct response parameters), I have made sure Opayo's IPs are allowed, the MD5 signatures match.

I think the problem is how I am "Responding to the Notification Post".

I am doing a standard WebRequest to send our RedirectUrl to SagePay - but the link here - [SagePay RedirectURL failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270496/sagepay-redirecturl-failure) - suggests it doesn't need that. Rather I should just **"write to the simple Response object."** The trouble is, I don't know what they mean by that.

Any help / experience with this, much appreciated.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer isn't too late to be useful to you.

You're suffering from the main issue I've always had with Opayo (formerly SagePay) - namely that their integration guides for developers are terrible.

As the Opayo Server integration method is identical to the old SagePay version, I found it helpful to follow the much more in-depth instructions from before they rebranded. You can find those instructions here:

https://www.opayo.co.uk/file/12246/download-document/SERVER_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_010814.pdf

In answer to your specific question, you can refer to page 68 of the above PDF guide. RE: You acknowledge receipt of the Notification POST, quote, "This is the plain text response part of the POST originated by the Server in the step above. Encoding must be as Name=Value fields separated by carriage-return linefeeds (CRLF)."

Literally, your script just has to print or echo something along the lines of:

```
Status=OK\r\n
StatusDetail=Hashes match - proceeding\r\n
RedirectURL=https://www.yoursite.com/endpointpage/
```

Or the equivalent for errors, aborts, etc.

Bear in mind that any output not formatted like the above will break the foldback process, so you must supress any errors or warnings your script might generate (ideally capturing them in a log or some other way).

Opayo give you basically no help in bugfixing, so if you continue to encounter errors you pretty much have to work in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured it out in the end. I share you feelings about the integration guides. In particular, the lack of code samples in whatever language.